# Prove the following statement: "Let $G$ be a group, and $N ⊲ G$. Then $G/N$ forms a group under the operation $(gN)(hN) = ghN$ "

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

I had this as a statement in my book, but I am unable to prove it using the four basic properties of a group:

1. Closure
2. Associativity
3. Existence of identity
4. Existence of inverses.

Comment: First you need 0. multiplication in $G/N$ is well-defined.

Comment: Multiplication as in "group operation"?! @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Use the fact $G$ satisfies all these properties.

Comment: The only non trivial thing to check that this binary operation is well defined and rest of things are clear because  elements of $G/N$ are representatives by the elements of $G$ which satisfies these properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that $G$ is group. For example, if $1 \in G$ denotes the identity element of $G$, we get

$(1N)(gN) = (1 \cdot g) N = gN = (g \cdot 1)N = (gN)(1N)$

for all $g \in G$. Thus $1N \in G/N$ is the identity element in the quotient group.